# Difference between F1 and F2 in Linux Consoles

Tags: gnome, login, gdm, tty

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I was experimenting with the TTY consoles that are Ctrl+Fn+Alt+F3, F4, F5, and up. I noticed that F1 and F2 both seem to be the graphical desktop. F2 is the one that I usually am in, which is my graphical desktop, but F1 puts me in the login screen, as if there's availability for 2 users to be logged in at once and to keep switching with just F1 and F2. Is this the case, or is there something else I have overlooked? Why is it like that in my system when everyone else seems to say that F1 goes to a TTY console. Also, if it's supposed to be like that, what is the point of 2 graphical desktops when you can just do the "Switch User" option in GNOME?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747339#c4) thread, that is functioning as intended as of gnome 3.0.

The login page runs on it's own x session and once the user authenticates, it creates a new session (thus runs on a new tty) and spawns the user's desktop under the new session.

In other X Destkop Environments, this might not be the case and thus others might still say F1 for desktop and F2 for TTY terminal.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot! I never knew how the login page worked

Comment: @AlexFullinator of course! 

Fun bit of trivia, Windows login shares similar functionality. The Windows Login process first spawns as a System account, and then creates a new session for the user once they authenticate. This has lead to all kind of *fun* shananigans spawning processes as System form the Login prompt on Windows in years past.

Comment: I've been wondering about this. Thanks, dude.

Comment: Note that this is not really tied to _specific_ virtual terminals. Ubuntu (and most other systemd systems) happens to be configured to use VT 1 for the greeter, but there’s not really anything (AFAIK) that forces that to be the case. Plenty of other distros still use VT 7 for this purpose, or some other VT. The unusual part about GNOME here is really just using a separate VT for the user session (AFAIK, it’s the only major DE that does this right now).